# Setting different S3 read permissions based on uploader

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to arrive at a situation, where

- one class of users can upload files that are subsequently not publicly available
- another class of users can upload files that are publicly available.

I think I need to use two IAM users:

- the first which has `putObject` permissions only and where I bake the secret key into javascript. (I use the AWS SDK `putObject` here, and bake in the first secret key)
- the other where I keep the secret key on the server, and provide signatures for uploading to signed-in users of the right category. (I ended up using a POST command for this with multipart form-data, as I could not understand how to do it with the SDK other than baking in the second secret key, which would be bad as files can be uploaded and downloaded)

But I'm struggling to set up bucket permissions that support some files being publicly available while others are not at all.

Is there a way, or do I need to use separate buckets?

**Update**
Based on the first comment, I tried to add `"acl": "public-read"` to my policy and POST form data fields. The signatures are matching correctly, but I am now getting a `forbidden` response from AWS, which I don't get when this field is absent (but then the uploads are not publicly visible)

Comment: I am not sure but you can achieve this using ACL header where you can set  public and private header for the uploaded S3 objects. So one class will have private header set and another will public header set when they are uploading the objects https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUTacl.html

Comment: @error2007s I tried, but without success - have updated my question

Comment: The way I do it is managing different folders inside the same bucket and two of them contain private files. To achieve this I assume a default "public-read" for the whole bucket, and then I add a "Bucket Policy" like this one: {"Version": "2008-10-17", "Statement":[{"Sid": "AllowPublicRead","Effect": "Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"*"},"Action": "s3:GetObject", "NotResource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/privatefolder1/*", "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/privatefolder2/*"]}]} , this policy allows me to define which folders contains private data, only accesible by S3 or using presignedURLs . I hope it helps.

Comment: OK, but that's nearly equivalent to having a separate bucket. I think I may just do that, as I can't see any downsides